# ROSJava Android connect w/o using RosActivity

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am somewhat new to ROSJava for Android.  Is there any way to connect an Android device to a Master without extending RosActivity?  Basically, all I am trying to do is publish 8 float values (4 (x,y) positions) to a master.

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43354/rosjava-android-connect-w/o-using-rosactivity/) by [MaxSchmid](https://answers.ros.org/users/3161/maxschmid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-09-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the old way they used to do things.  I was also in the situation where I absolutely could not use RosActivity (since I was already extending).  I dug in to their ROSActivity and a few of their tutorials to find the below.  Hope it helps.

The method I currently use is:

```
nodeConfiguration = NodeConfiguration
                        .newPublic(InetAddressFactory.newNonLoopback()
                                .getHostAddress());

String hostMaster = prefs.getString("ros_IP", "");
Integer port = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("ros_port",
                        ""));
URI uri = URI.create("http://" + hostMaster + ":" + port);
nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(uri);

nodeMainExecutor = DefaultNodeMainExecutor.newDefault();
nodeMainExecutor.execute(<NAMEOFNODECLASS>, nodeConfiguration);
```

I am using a preference menu to hold the hostMaster IP and port, but you can change those directly.

I have been working with ROSJava a lot lately and have been looking for some people who may be more involved in it to hit questions back and forth.  I hope this helps you.

---

Originally posted by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) with karma: 213 on 2012-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2012-09-23**:
Does this solution work for you or do you need another way?